# Call webhook at specific times for millions of events

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks

Suppose you are designing a birthday app that will send an email to users on the exact date and time of their birthday. Suppose also that there is webhook that will handle the delivery of the email. In this system, birthday emails can be scheduled months in advance and the system must be able to support millions of users.

This is a reasonable approximation of the problem I'm trying to solve, except with the events happening much more frequently than once a year for each user. What I'd like to do is schedule a webhook call when a user enters their birthday. Is there a particular technology or service that does this?

We have a Django app on AWS. I looked into SQS and SNS, but these don't seem to be the right tools for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API Gateway + AWS Lambda to post the event to Kinesis.
Run multiple EC2 instances using KCL to consume the events and act on it.

Comment: Can you go into more detail? How would you set up the scheduling system with API Gateway and Lambda? Can you provide some links to documentation?